# How to record a time-limited video with Adobe AIR for iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, video, air

**I am trying to record a time-limited video with Adobe AIR for iOS.**

For example, I want to implement the following function. Start a one-minute timer before launching CameraUI to record video. When the timeout event happens after one minute, stop recording video, close the CameraUI view and obtain the video data so far.

I have several questions related to that.

1. ***How to stop recording video from outside the CameraUI view(in this case, from the timeout event handler) and then close the CemeraUI view?*** As far as I know, to close the CameraUI view, the only way is to press the [Use Video] button or the [Cancel] button from inside the CameraUI view. Is it possible to close it from outside?
2. ***Even if the first problem mentioned above is solved, then how can I get the video data so far(in this case, the video data before the timeout).*** I know that normally we can get a MediaPromise object from MediaEvent parameter of the  complete handler, and read the video data from the MediaPromise object. But obviously in this case, we can not access the MediaPromise object just because the complete handler itself will not be executed since the [Use Video] button is not pressed.
3. ***Is it possible to add a stopwatch to show possible remaining recording time when CameraUI view is open?*** It seems that the CameraUI automatically uses the full screen of iOS device(in my case, iPad) and there is no extra space to show the stopwatch.

   Are there any solutions or workarounds about the three problem above? I really appreciate it if anyone has any idea about this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with video specially on iOS, so I just putting down my thoughts on this issue, sorry if you find it useless.

1. I suppose it's impossible to write video outside CameraUI (unless you write your own ANE for that), and I think it's a bad design why do you need that?
2. Answer the same as 1.
3. It impossible to add display objects at native windows (once again unless you write your own ANE)

In general if you want more freedom to work with video in AIR you can do it in three ways:

1. Write you own ANE.
2. To stream you video data to your own server, and do whatever you want with it.
3. Least reliable way but you can try it. There is [FLVRecorder](https://code.google.com/p/flvrecorder/) library, I never tried it and even don't know does it work at all. Or you can try own approach (save you stage to bitmaps with some framerate and then encode it to video). It just suggestion I don't know will it work at all.

Hope my thoughts will help.

Comment: Dear Dmitry, thank you very much for your reply, again. Yes , maybe I need to write my own ANE to implement this. I wanted to implement the time-limited video function because I planed to upload the video to server side. If the video is too large, the upload will be a very time-consuming process which users can not tolerate. So I decided to implement a time-limited short video so the upload will not take too long. Do you have some other advice to my design? Looking forward to your reply again.

Comment: I think in you case simplest way will be to write video to file locally with CameraUI, then check it's size and if it's too big show message to user, if it's apropriate size upload it to server.

Comment: A little harder way - if size of recorded video file too big  crop it then upload to server (harder because you have to know low level format of video file). Or may be there is a library to work with video files but I've never heard about it

Comment: Dmitry, glad to hear from you. In fact, recently I also considered the first solution you mentioned above. It is a good solution, but we may face the problem that user may have to record several times before he/she finally clear the size limit successfully, because, you know, we can not simply calculate the video size from the record time in advance. Anyway, it is solution deserved to try.

Comment: And the second solution you mentioned is a new solution to me. Do you mean I should compress the video in client side? Theoretically, this is possible, but I think the video process is a time-consuming and battery-consuming work, which will eat up the battery of device soon. Thank you very much to supply two solutions for me. I will consider them more in detail.

Comment: No I mean crop video file so it would be desired one minute length, and then upload to server. But you have to know low level format of video file, and I suppose from your questions for you this way will be really hard.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? I am also researching some ways to do it but couldn't find a proper solution yet.